# When submitting a power bi custom visual for certification we got 1120.1.2.2 Invalid SupportURL Content error?

Tags: powerbi

Here is the error we received from Microsoft Power BI Custom Visuals Team.

> 1120.1.2.2  Invalid SupportURL Content  The SupportURL element content is missing or invalid. Please update the offer to include a completely
>   defined SupportURL element and re-submit your offer.

What needs to be done for the above message?

**We already have the support url in the pbiviz.json**
[image]

**Also in the partner center** 
[image]

**Still we got above mentioned error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom visual doesn't met the requirements for "[easy identification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/marketplace/certification-policies#11201-easy-identification)" by not specifying `SupportURL`. It must be filled in `pbiviz.json` file, as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/office-store#getting-an-app-package-xml):

> Before you create the pbiviz package, you must fill the following fields in the `pbiviz.json` file:
>
> - description
> - **supportUrl**
> - author
> - name
> - email

The support URL must meet the [following guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/readiness/readiness-checklist-h-help-support#Support):

> The support page needs to include the following contact options and docs:
>
> - Email
> - Phone number
> - Live-chat (if possible)
> - Address
> - Defined service level agreements (SLAs).

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have edited my question please see it.

Comment: In this case https://sharepointwebpartassets.blob.core.windows.net/$web/support.html is threated as invalid. Try with a normal domain or subdomain URLs.

Comment: Could you please tell me why this is invalid?

Comment: It misses address and SLA at least. It also must be different that the HelpURL (which we do not know).